# Laravel Validation - Multiple fields unique

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Is there a way to validate a unique `$data` based on multiple fields being unique at the same time?

I have a table `schedule` with the following `Schema`

```
<?php
Schema::create('schedules', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id', false, true);
        $table->integer('client_id', false, true);
        $table->integer('day', false, true);
        $table->integer('month', false, true);
        $table->integer('year', false, true);
        $table->enum('type', array('template', 'revision', 'common'));
        $table->string('name', 50)->default('Untitled Template');
        $table->boolean('is_published');
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
});
?>
```

For me, there can only be one `common` type schedule for a given `day`, `month`, `year`. There can be infinite number of `revision` for the same date, however, there can only be one `is_published = false` `revision` at a time. `templates` ignore the date (doesn't matter what you enter, they will always be set to zero).

I can't imagine how to apply the [uniqueWith-validator](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator), since my `day`, `month`, `year` should only be unique IF the `type = 'common'`.

Is this too abstract to be used with a Validator and should I just manually search for existing entries?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Comment: I updated my question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: That's pretty complicated. [User defined variable and unique groups from Vocal](https://github.com/lakedawson/vocal#extended) might help, otherwise custom validation is probably the way to go.